# Why isn't my ImageSearch command working?

Tags: autohotkey

I am writing a script which uses the `ImageSearch` command.

The script starts by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> and it scans from `900,55` to `1005,72`.
If it locates any of these 3 identical images, it should send <kbd>F1</kbd>, otherwise it should keep scanning until I press <kbd>F12</kbd>.

I tried changing the resolution and such but to no success.

```
F3::
SendMode , Input
SetMouseDelay , -1
SetBatchLines , -1
Loop
{
    ImageSearch ,,, 0 , 0 , A_ScreenWidth , A_ScreenHeight , para1.png
    bT := ErrorLevel ? bT : 1
    ImageSearch ,,, 0 , 0 , A_ScreenWidth , A_ScreenHeight , para2.bmp
    bT := ErrorLevel ? bT : 1
    ImageSearch ,,, 0 , 0 , A_ScreenWidth , A_ScreenHeight , para3.png
    bT := ErrorLevel ? bT : 1
    If bT
    {
        bT := 0
        Send , {F1}
        Sleep , 100
    }   
}
Return
f12::ExitApp
```

thanks for the correction @GoldenLizard

Comment: Please explain what seems to be the issue?  I don't see a question here.

Comment: @Yane its not working bro, and i asked to help with the start hotkey / search area